# QUnit output: visual separation of modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

My tests may look like this:

```
module("some module");

test("test A", ...);
test("test B", ...);

module("other module");

test("test C", ...);
test("test D", ...);
```

The output of QUnit will look like this

```
1. test A (0, 0, 0)
2. test B (0, 0, 0)
3. test C (0, 0, 0)
4. test D (0, 0, 0)
```

Is it possible to make QUnit output the module names?
I would love to have:

```
some module
1. test A (0, 0, 0)
2. test B (0, 0, 0)

other module
3. test C (0, 0, 0)
4. test D (0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [QUnit documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit), there is a callback on module start (and end), at which point you could modify the DOM.

```
QUnit.moduleStart = function(name) {
  var tests = document.getElementById("qunit-tests");

  if ( tests ) {    
    var mod = document.createElement("h2");
    mod.innerHTML = name;
    tests.appendChild( mod );
  }
};
```

Putting stuff in the middle of a list is kind of naughty DOM wise, but it seems to work, at least in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Justin Love's solution didn't work for me, but you can insert the following JQuery Javascript after your test to achieve the same desired result:

```
QUnit.done(function( details )
{
    $("#qunit-tests > li ") //the test rows
    .each(function(index, Element){
        var moduleName = $(".module-name", this).text();
        if (moduleName !== $(".module-name", this.previousSibling).text())
        {
            $(this).before( //prepend header to it
                function(){
                    return "<h3 class='module-header'>" + moduleName + "</h3>"
                ;})
        }
    });
});
```